# Name Month optgroup with child name week

Tags: php

Please see my PHP code

```
$data= '<select>';

for($y = 1; $y <= 52; $y++) {
    $numweek = date("W",strtotime('+ '.$y.' weeks', mktime(0,0,0,1,1,$year,-1))); // display 1 to 52
    $namemonth = date("F",strtotime('+ '.$y.' weeks', mktime(0,0,0,1,1,$year,-1))); // display january to december

    $data .= '<optgroup label="'.$namemonth.'">\n';

    for($x = 1; $x <= 52; $x++) {
        $data.= '<option value="'.$x.'"'.($x != $week ? '' : ' selected="selected"').'>Week '.$x.'</option>';   
    }   

    $data.= '</optgroup>';
}

$data.= '</select>';
```

I want to display:

```
January
  Week 1
  Week 2
  Week 3
  Week 4
February
  Week 5
  Week 6
  Week 7
  Week 8
.......
December
  ...
  Week 52
```

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Here,I just mention weeknumber for two month. If you want to get for all the month then you can modify  **$inputArray** Array.

```
$inputArray = ["1(Jan)","2(feb)"];
$weekRange = [];
foreach ($inputArray as $val) {
    // parse the input string to extract the month
    list(, $month) = sscanf($val, '%d(%[^)]s)');
    // Get timestamp for the 1st day of the requested month (using current year)
    $startMonth = strtotime('1-' . $month);
    // Get the ISO week number for the 1st day of the requested month
    $startWeek = date('W', $startMonth);
    // Get timestamp for the last day of the requested month (using current year)
    $endMonth = strtotime('+1 Month -1 Day', $startMonth);
    // Get the ISO week number for the last day of the requested month
    $endWeek = date('W', $endMonth);
    // get a range of weeks from the start week to the end week
    if ($startWeek > $endWeek) {
        // start week for january in previous year
        $weekRange[$val] = range(1, $endWeek);
        array_unshift($weekRange, intval($startWeek));
    } else {
        $weekRange[$val] = range($startWeek, $endWeek);
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($weekRange);
exit;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(        
    [1(Jan)] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 5
        )

    [2(feb)] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 7
            [3] => 8
            [4] => 9
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks Bhavin Solanki